# How to get next Revision number in SVN to insert into a binary file?

Tags: svn, binary, version, executable, revision

We have binary files (firmware) which we want to version control, but which are created using tools that are incompatible with Subversion's source code model.  For example, one of these binary files is the configuration file for a motor controller. I can run a script to put the version number in the right place using a script as part of the check in process, but I cannot put the $Revision$ keyword there. There are other types of binary firmware files as well.

The only solution I've seen so far was just use the info from the svnversion command and add one. This doesn't guarantee the number is what subversion will record on check in, but it does make it distinct.

The problem with this solution is finding the version again at a later date. (e.g., this file has rev number 5164, but I can only find rev 5163 followed by 5198 in subversion. So which one is it?)

I understand we should change the source code, not the binary, but we cannot do this. As I said, these essentially are not compiled files. They must be tracked, preferably with embedded version numbers, but cannot be built.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to embed the revision number before the file is added? Best practice is to embed the revision number afterwards (i.e. when the packages are created).

Comment: Okay. That's interesting but doesn't seem complete. It could almost work for my configuration file. So I check in my working copy with version number 5142, and it is assigned version 5164. The release process finds that number and modifies the file at release time. So the file on the product has the right version 5164, though the file in subversion still has the old number 5142.

Comment: Now the tougher problem is the firmware binaries. These start as VHDL code and the build tool is such that you cannot guarantee the same binary output even with identical source input. (It has to do with how lines are routed within the circuit.) The tested binaries are being checked in as part of the package. So these cannot be modified (recompiling might produce a circuit with different routes and thus different signal timings). So that is the big reason to see what the version number will be BEFORE check in. They seem to have a workaround, but I'll keep waiting for something better.

Comment: So, you can add a revision number to the binary. However, the process is non-deterministic, and it is important to save the exact result. Right? In this case I suggest to generate a UUID and encode the UUID into the binary. When adding the file to the SVN repository, encode the UUID either into the file name or add it to the commit comment. Later you can parse the output of `svn -v log` to find the corresponding SVN revision number.

Comment: @nosid Thanks. That could work. It is similar to what they were planning to do. The key is putting the ID in the log. It is a doable workaround.                                                         . <p>                                                                      It still seems strange that there is no way to get the global revision number. So many others have posted this same request. Of course the real cause is the global revision number as opposed to a file level revision number.

Comment: It's easy to get the _global revision number_: `svn info ^/` prints it. The problem is, that you can't query the revision number and commit a new revision atomically, because somebody else can commit a change between the two operations.